# How do I get a complete 'recursive' tree/graph of task dependencies in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

When I for example `inspect tree compile` on a simple sbt project:

```
sbt> inspect tree compile
[info] compile:compile = Task[sbt.inc.Analysis]
[info]   +-compile:compile::compileInputs = Task[sbt.Compiler$Inputs]
[info]   | +-*/*:compileOrder = Mixed
[info]   | +-compile:dependencyClasspath = Task[scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]]]
[info]   | +-*/*:maxErrors = 100
[info]   | +-compile:sources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   | +-compile:scalacOptions = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]]
[info]   | +-*/*:javacOptions = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]]
[info]   | +-*:compilers = Task[sbt.Compiler$Compilers]
[info]   | +-compile:incCompileSetup = Task[sbt.Compiler$IncSetup]
[info]   | +-compile:compile::streams = Task[sbt.std.TaskStreams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]   | | +-*/*:streamsManager = Task[sbt.std.Streams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-*/*:sourcePositionMappers = Task[scala.collection.Seq[scala.Function1[xsbti.Position, scala.Option[xsbti.Position..
[info]   | +-compile:classDirectory = target/scala-2.10/classes
[info]   | 
[info]   +-compile:compile::streams = Task[sbt.std.TaskStreams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]     +-*/*:streamsManager = Task[sbt.std.Streams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
```

The 'depth' of this tree is limited: for example, it mentions `compile:sources`, which itself has a number of dependencies:

```
sbt> inspect tree compile:sources
[info] compile:sources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   +-compile:unmanagedSources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[ja..
[info]   | +-*/*:excludeFilter = sbt.SimpleFileFilter@745ef9f2
[info]   | +-*:baseDirectory = /tmp/xxxx
[info]   | +-*/*:unmanagedSources::includeFilter = sbt.SimpleFilte..
[info]   | +-*/*:sourcesInBase = true
[info]   | +-compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories = List(/tmp/xxxx/s..
[info]   |   +-compile:javaSource = src/main/java
[info]   |   | +-compile:sourceDirectory = src/main
[info]   |   |   +-*:sourceDirectory = src
[info]   |   |   | +-*:baseDirectory = /tmp/xxxx
[info]   |   |   |   +-*:thisProject = Project(id: xxxx, base: /tm..
[info]   |   |   |   
[info]   |   |   +-compile:configuration = compile
[info]   |   |   
[info]   |   +-compile:scalaSource = src/main/scala
[info]   |     +-compile:sourceDirectory = src/main
[info]   |       +-*:sourceDirectory = src
[info]   |       | +-*:baseDirectory = /tmp/xxxx
[info]   |       |   +-*:thisProject = Project(id: xxxx, base: /tm..
[info]   |       |   
[info]   |       +-compile:configuration = compile
[info]   |       
[info]   +-compile:managedSources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java..
[info]     +-compile:sourceGenerators = List()
```

I'd like to somehow be able to analyze the 'complete picture' - for example, I have a project for which the `assembly` task appears to run some tasks twice. Right now it's quite hard to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Can you open a feature request for this?

I believe once the sbt-server work starts hitting UIs, we'll see something in this space, but it'd stil be good to track this.